# In stored procedure, need to access the column value in the variable where Tablename is taken as a variable too

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_testing

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @STATE INT,@TBLNAME sysname,@TrID VARCHAR(50),@FAMILYID VARCHAR(50),@SQL varchar(8000)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT TrID,TableName 
FROM LogTable
WHERE Prefix='vid'
AND YEAR(DateTime)=YEAR(GETDATE())AND MONTH(DateTime)=MONTH(GETDATE())AND  DAY(DateTime)=DAY(GETDATE())

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @TrID,@TBLNAME

IF(@TBLNAME='Student' OR @TBLNAME='Family' OR @TBLNAME='College')
BEGIN
**select @SQL='SELECT MemberID FROM'+' '+@TBLNAME+' '+'where TrId='+@TrID
select @FAMILYID=EXEC(@SQL)**
```

In this line, its gving me an error.

```
select @SQL='select @ID=(SELECT MemberID FROM'+' '+@TBLNAME+' '+'where TrId='+@TrID +')'
```

as well as in this too

```
exec(@sql) 

END

END
GO
```

I need to put the MemberID in the variable @ID

Hi, I have done few changes as explained below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_TESTSP]

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max),@TABLENAME sysname,@id nvarchar(max)
    SELECT @TABLENAME='student'
    select @SQL= 'select @id=MemberID FROM'+' '+@TABLENAME+' '+'where TrId=11091'
    exec sp_executesql @SQL,'@id nvarchar(max)output',@id=@id output
    --select exec (@SQL)

END
```

but getting an error as:

> Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of `sp_executesql` where the formal arguments of your dynamic query are declared, `'@id nvarchar(max)output'`, should be a unicode string. In Transact-SQL, to specify that a string constant is in fact a unicode string, you need to put `N` before the opening quotation mark, like this:

```
N'@id nvarchar(max)output'
```

So your `USP_TESTSP` should look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_TESTSP]

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max),@TABLENAME sysname,@id nvarchar(max)
    SELECT @TABLENAME='student'
    select @SQL= 'select @id=MemberID FROM'+' '+@TABLENAME+' '+'where TrId=11091'
    exec sp_executesql @SQL,N'@id nvarchar(max)output',@id=@id output
    --select exec (@SQL)

END
```

Comment: I am getting Invalid column name '11091'.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) with an output parameter:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL='SELECT @FAMILYID = MemberID FROM ' + @TBLNAME + ' where TrId=' + @TrID
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@FAMILYID int out', @FAMILYID = @FAMILYID out
```

Comment: getting an error as: Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: maybe you have to change `'@FAMILYID int out'` to `'@FAMILYID nvarchar(max) out'`?

Comment: I did !!! i edited my above question. I am facing the error as i mentioned to you on SQL server 2008

Comment: @Vids: Sorry, the second parameter should have been unicode, as AndriyM has already suggested.  Now updated in this answer too.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
select @SQL='SELECT @FAMILYID=MemberID FROM'+' '+@TBLNAME+' '+'where TrId='+@TrID
select EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: For me this prints `must declare the scalar variable "@familyid"`  Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Its not working on Sql Server 2008. Its giving the same error as you mentioned above

Comment: Yes, I confirm. Now I see is a sql server.

Comment: g an error as: Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar' for @andomar solution